# Is it 'legal' to differentiate a differential operator?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Consider the differential operator : $D^n$

Where, $ D = \frac{d}{dx} $ .

Then is it mathematically legal to differentiate the above operator w.r.t $D$

i.e.  $$\frac{d(D^n)}{dD}  = nD^{n-1}$$ ?

(I know $D$ is non-commutative )

Note : Sorry in advance if it's a mistake .

Comment: Not really, what would that even mean? How do you make a small perturbation of a differential operator?

Comment: Maybe you could define something like this with fractional calculus?

Comment: @copper.hat thank you for the comment . I'm just following the algebra and pattern . I didn't gave a logical thought the way you did .

Comment: Well. If $D$ is any linear operator, then we can certainly define the algebra $A=\Bbb{R}[D]$ of linear operators it generates over the reals. And if $A$ is isomorphic to the polynomial ring, then in $A$ we can define a derivation $\delta:A\to A$ obeying the rule $\delta(D^n)=nD^{n-1}$. But something tells me this is not quite what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't really possible to do this.

In general you can only differentiate real functions.

Also you should be aware there is a bit of notational abuse that has mislead you a bit.  With $D^n$ the $n$ isn't an exponent but shorthand for repeatedly applying the operator. So $D^4(f) = D(D(D(D(f)))) $

Comment: Complex valued functions?

Comment: @DavidPeterson yes complex valued functions and more broadly any Differentiable manifold can be differentiated.  But I wanted to keep the answer simple.